# How to update a type as datatype reference in another table

Tags: oracle, types, reference

```
create or replace type My_abc_typ FORCE as object    
(
  ...
  Pqr  pqr_typ,
  ... 
)
/
```

Actually the Table `My_abc` is created as

```
CREATE TABLE "ABC"."My_abc" OF "ABC"."My_abc_TYP" 
(... ,
...)
```

and primary keys and indexes are there for this

the problem is in type i ve changed the data type of a particular column , and compiled it... its working fine.
but the table is not reflecting the change... its showing

```
(
  ...
  Pqr  (null),
  ... 
)
```

in order to modify that column alone i executed the following query

```
alter table  My_abc modify Pqr  pqr_typ;
```

the following error appears

> SQL Error: ORA-04063: table "ABC.My_abc" has errors
>   04063. 00000 -  "%s has errors"
>   *Cause:    Attempt to execute a stored procedure or use a view that has
>              errors.  For stored procedures, the problem could be syntax errors
>              or references to other, non-existent procedures.  For views,
>              the problem could be a reference in the view's defining query to
>              a non-existent table.
>              Can also be a table which has references to non-existent or
>              inaccessible types.
>   *Action:   Fix the errors and/or create referenced objects as necessary.

Comment: no its already existing... and the syntax is tat....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of re-creating type:
modify the typ attribute as:

```
ALTER TYPE my_abc_typ MODIFY ATTRIBUTE (pqr VARCHAR2(20))CASCADE NOT INCLUDING TABLE DATA;
```

Link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjadv.htm

Thanks.